Probability of their meeting
Two cyclists, A and B, are on a circular track with a circumference of 20 km. Cyclist A starts from point P at any time between 8 AM and 10 AM and rides clockwise with a speed of 5 km/hr. Cyclist B starts from point Q (directly opposite P on the track) at any time between 8 AM and 10 AM and rides counterclockwise with a speed of 4 km/hr. Assuming all start times are equally likely, find the probability that A and B will meet on the track before 11 AM.

Hi! What have you tried so far?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

There is a lot in this question - it is a nice, interesting question and I've thought about it a lot. However, unless you are able to first show what you have tried, what worked, what did not work, some context (where is this question from?) site policy discourages me from providing an answer either in full or in part. See the comment above for some links to help improve the question.
